# Storring and pulling meta-information of a docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Is there any general way of storing meta-information about a docker image along with the image e.g. about the contained software versions? If so is there a way of fetching this information with the docker tool? Directly scrapping the docker.io index might be an option but would not be compatible with a private index.

I would expect something to e.g. get the content of the README file sitting next to the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a new feature added in Version 1.6

- https://blog.docker.com/2015/04/docker-release-1-6/
- https://docs.docker.com/userguide/labels-custom-metadata/